# Unable to interact with elments using $$ sign in WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I'm using WebdrivreIO(v7) but unable to export $$ value from another file. If I'm working with the same file it's working fine, but another file not working. not sure what's wrong here

*sample.js*

```
module.exports = {
details: $$('.agent-rows p.name'),
}
```

*script_file.js*

```
When("Getting the list from the listing page"){
    const sample=require("./sample.js");
    console.log("value 1"+ await sample.details) // Output : nothing empty
    console.log("value 2"+ await sample.details[0]) // Output : undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you sure you are not doing any thing between constant sample, console.log lines? require will trigger the details property as soon as you call it .

so if you are trying the below thing , it won't work

```
const elem = sample.details
//do something for the element to be present
(await elem)[0].dosomething
```

because sample.details will trigger the fetch process before the element is present. await is used to wait for an async process to complete, not to trigger it.

use instead:

```
  module.exports = {
         details: ()=>{$$('.agent-rows p.name')},
   }
```

in code:

```
const elem = sample.details
//do something for the element to be present
(await elem())[0].dosomething  //here you are triggering the fetch
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a typo `s`. It should be `sample.detail` not `sample.details`.

```
When("Getting the list from the listing page"){
    const sample=require("./sample.js");
    console.log("value 1"+ await sample.detail) // 'detail' not 'details'
}
```

Comment: What did you get? Are you sure that the `$$('.agent-rows p.name')` elements are on the page? Can you see it in the DOM?

Comment: Yes, definitely sure about that